# Vkcoin выдаёт ошибку при использовании longPoll()

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
from vkcoinapi import *
coin = VKCoin(key = 'Ключ', merchantId = ид)
coin.longPoll()
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'VKCoin' object has no attribute 'wss_url'